# Cannot open HTTP web page for Cisco Aironet 1815i Autonomous Access Point

Tags: cisco, access-point, aironet

I have two Cisco Aironet 1815i Autonomous Access Point connected to the network already and getting IP addresses from the DHCP server. But I am not able to open the web page for the configuration.

When I try to connect to the Access Point using the console port, I keep getting below shown error:

```
[*04/27/2018 00:25:53.2299] CAPWAP State: Discovery 
[*04/27/2018 00:25:53.2399] Discovery Request sent to 255.255.255.255, discovery type UNKNOWN(0)
```

I don't understand one thing when the access point is autonomous, then why it's trying to find the WLC? The firmware on the access point is 8.3.111.0 and model number is AIR-AP1815I-E-K9.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the AP is trying to do a discovery of a controller, then it is NOT an autonomous access point.

Answer (score 0):

See what firmware version it is running. If the firmware is someting like ap3g1-k9w7xxx then is it autonomous mode. If it is ap3g1-k9w8 then it is a lightweight ap.

```
cisco-ap-02#dir flash:/
Directory of flash:/

    2  -rwx         203   Mar 1 1993 00:00:24 +00:00  env_vars
    3  -rwx        2843   Mar 1 1993 13:17:18 +00:00  config.txt
  215  drwx        1152   Jan 1 1970 00:10:58 +00:00  ap3g1-k9w7-mx.153-3.JD4
    5  -rwx        5483   Mar 1 1993 13:17:18 +00:00  private-config
    6  -rwx        2072   Mar 1 1993 13:17:19 +00:00  private-multiple-fs
```